# Why my code does not output to a text file

Tags: c

I have written the following program which runs well when you run it from the IDE. However, when I want to test it by taking input from a `inp.txt` file and outputting to `out.txt` file, it does not do so.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
}*start;

void insertatend(int d)
{
  struct node *n;
  n=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  n->data=d;
  n->next=NULL;

  if(start==NULL)
  {
    start=n;
  }

  else
  {
    struct node *tmp;
    for(tmp=start;tmp->next!=NULL;tmp=tmp->next);
    tmp->next=n;
  }
}

int max(int  a,int b)
{
  int c=(a>b)?a:b;
  return c;
}

int maxCoins(int n)
{
  int arr[n+1],i;
  arr[0]=0;
  arr[1]=1;
  arr[2]=2;
  arr[3]=3;

  if(n>2)
  {


    for(i=3;i<=n;i++)
    {
      int k= arr[(int)(i/2)]+arr[(int)(i/3)]+arr[(int)(i/4)];
      arr[i]=max(i,k);
    }
  }

  return arr[n];
}

int main(void)
{
  int coins,i;
  start=NULL;
  struct node*p;

  while(scanf("%d",&coins)>0)
  {
    insertatend(coins);
  }

  for(p=start;p!=NULL;p=p->next)
  {
    printf("%d\n",maxCoins(p->data));
  }

  getchar();

  return 0;
}
```

---

I try to do the following on my command prompt `ByteTest.exe<inp.txt>out.txt`, but no changes are made to `out.txt` file.

I terminate the input to my program by entering `CTRL+Z`. Does that have anything to do with this ?

---

The `inp.txt and out.txt` may, for example contain

---

```
inp.txt      out.txt

12             13
24             27
26             27
```

Comment: Why would you expect your program to output to a file? You are not using any file access/writing functionality within your program? Are you expecting it to work by piping output like from a shell command line `ls -a > file_list.txt` ??

Comment: Yeah. I am trying for something like that

Comment: I don't see any problem with how you're doing things.

Comment: Please try out my code in your system to see if it works !

Comment: try gcc ThisProg.c -o ByteTest.exe

Answer (score 2):

Your problem might be:

```
while(scanf("%d",&coins)>0)
```

This returns number of chars. You are not checking the value of coins here, but the length of the input string.